# HTML Using Bootstrap CSS Not Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 panels and trying to figure out why a page is not responsive on mobile devices.  It displays properly on a desktop browser, but doesn't view optimized on mobile devices.

The [panel examples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) on the Bootstrap site do indeed display optimized on mobile.

Am I missing something?

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>a title</title>
  </head>

  <body>  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-body">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><h1 class="media-heading">This is a heading using h1s.</h1></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4 top-buffer">

            </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>    
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a viewport tag in the head of your HTML. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Like this:

```
 <meta content='maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width' name='viewport'>
```

Except it could be argued that disabling zoom is a bad idea if your text is too small to read, so take care to test it on a variety of devices with different users in mind.

Comment: Awesome.  That was it!

Comment: Yes, disabling zoom is _usually_ A Bad Thing™. Remove `maximum-scale=1.0,` to bring it back :)

Comment: This was a real live saver!